# git как сделать изменения которые не будут попадать в commit

Tags: git, list, commit, change

В проекте есть изменения, которые не надо добавлять в commit. Как можно сделать так, что бы именно эти изменения в этих файлах не попадали в commit, а все остальные попадали. Их я не хочу добавлять, так как они нужны только для работы на моей локальной машине.

Comment: Не делать `add .`, а делать `add КОНКРЕТНЫЙ файл`, чтобы попали только нужные файл коммит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1.

Если через командную строку:

```
git add file-1 file-2 file-3
```

так будут добавляться только те файлы, что необходимо добавить в коммит.

---

Вариант 2.

Можно создать файл `.gitignore` в котором можно перечислить либо пути до папок, либо до конкретных файлов, которые должны игнорироваться гитом и не заносится в отслеживаемые файлы

`.gitignore` может находиться в любой папке проекта. Может быть в корне, может быть в тех папках, где лежат непосредственно файлы, а можно хоть в каждой папке

---

Но я в целом рекомендую использовать UI для гита, если есть возможность. Т.к. это намного удобно. Особенно если нужно выделить для коммита к примеру 99 файлов из 102.